# Avoid QGIS adds semicolon to my CSV layer thus merging two fields

Tags: qgis, csv

I'm mapping flight data and came across an anomaly when importing my data in QGIS. For some flights QGIS merges two columns together as shown in the photo thus moving the following columns.

How can I avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the import dialog, in the `File Format` settings choose `Custom delimiters`and check the box next to `Semicolon` to solve the problem.

It seems your data source is inconsistent and uses semicolons as well as other characters (probably commas) as delimiters. Without defining semicolons as delimiters, they are recognized as part of the data.

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering me a few days ago. It has given a little boost trying to find my errors. The problem resided in the way I was treating my data on excel on which I would lose a lot of data. I switched to R and my problems went away, but it takes a little getting used to at first.

Comment: I think you can handle your data in Excel in a way that you don't lose any data. Or work in a text editor to create csv files. No need for R - but if you know R, of course this is an option.